# Using iPod in Banshee alongside iTunes?

Tags: banshee, sync, itunes

I'm running Ubuntu (11.04) and Banshee (up-to-date from the Banshee Team ppa), and I have a 1st gen iPod Touch (version 3.1.3 7E18).

Up until now I've synced and managed the iPod using my MacBook Pro. However, my music collection has begun to outgrow the MacBook's disk space, so I've been considering my alternatives...

What I've been thinking of doing is moving my entire music collection to my Ubuntu box - which has a much larger hard-drive - and using Banshee to manage my music and sync it to my iPod.

However, I would still like to install and manage Apps on my iPod too, so I presume I will still need to connect the iPod to iTunes on the MacBook occasionally too.

So I guess my question is: is it possible to use Ubuntu Banshee to manage music on my iPod and Mac iTunes to manage apps on it, without the two conflicting or otherwise messing up the contents of the iPod?

(And if so, any suggestions about what options to use in either bits of software would be much appreciated. For example, in iTunes will I need to set music syncing to "manual"?)

Thanks in advance,

thoughton.

Answer (score 4):

This might or might not help but this is what i did. When i first bought my IPod Touch and Ipod Shuffle i synced them in Banshee with no problem but for music only. mp3 files. For other stuff i put the touch in itunes on a friends mac. I was afraid of some corrupt error but nothing happened. Ever since i have been doing it in any way i want. Sync with Banshee or when am on my friends Mac i sync them there. No weird stuff has happened. Am using the Banshee ppa.

Comment: Thanks CYREX, that's very encouraging! Out of interest, do you remember whether you had to set any special options in your friend's iTunes to stop it from trying to sync music to or from the iPod?

Comment: Sorry he was the one that did it the first time. Normally i took it to his house and while he was doing that i was doing something else. But i did ask and he said he just plugged the device in, itune opened it and the end. No additional stuff to do. That was the first time. The rest of the times i just plugged it at his Mac and just sync. I will ask if he did something the first time just to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

For me I just synced with Banshee (Music only) and then I synced with my iPod touch (32GB 4'th gen) with iTunes for apps and music...no issues or anything....seemed to work just fine without freaking out :) i don't remember any special steps taken though... I think it was just plug and play :D

Comment: Brilliant, thanks zkriesse! It sounds like I should just plug it in and see what happens then - judging from your experiences it sounds like may actually just work...